# Determine if a Varchar field has a Numeric entry

Tags: sql, sql-server, type-conversion

I've got a field in a table that has a DataType of varchar(10).  This field contains numeric values that are formatted as a varchar, for the sole purpose of being used to join two tables together.  Some sample data would be:

```
AcctNum        AcctNumChar   
2223333          2223333   
3324444          3324444
```

For some records, the table sometimes thinks this field (AcctNumChar) is numeric and the join doesn't work properly.  I then have to use an Update statement to re-enter the value as a varchar.

Is there any way to determine whether or not the field has a varchar or numeric value in it, using a query?  I'm trying to narrow down which records are faulty without having to wait for one of the users to tell me that their query isn't returning any hits.

Comment: But why do you store AcctNum as char and sometimes as numeric? Adjust your table definitions and the problem will be gone!

Comment: It's supposed to always be varchar, but for some reason some of the records loaded as numeric.  Not even sure how it happened, but it did.

Comment: The column is always varchar. But if You join a varchar field to a numeric field, then the system want to convert the varchar to numeric. I think this is  the problem. So make sure that, when You join a numeric field to this varchar field, then convert the numeric field to varchar.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `isnumeric()` for a generic comparison, for instance:

```
select (case when isnumeric(acctnum) = 1 then cast(acctnum as decimal(10, 0))
        end)
```

In your case, though, you only seem to want integers:

```
(case when acctnum not like '%[^0-9]%' then cast(acctnum as decimal(10, 0)) 
 end)
```

However, I would strongly suggest that you update the table to change the data type to a number, which appears to be the correct type for the value.  You can also add a computed column as:

```
alter table t add AcctNum_Number as 
    (case when acctnum not like '%[^0-9]%' then cast(acctnum as decimal(10, 0)) 
     end)
```

Then you can use the computed column rather than the character column.

Comment: `not like '%[0-9]%'` this is not working for `abc123`. It works only if all symbols are nondigit.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to check if `varchar` column contains numeric value but I recommend to you to us [TRY_CONVERT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) function.

It will give you `NULL` if the value cannot be converted to number. For example, to get all records that have numeric values, you can do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM [table]
WHERE TRY_CONVERT(INT, [value]) IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL) functions here to solve your purpose.

reference here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187928.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

IsNumeric worked, TRY_CONVERT didn't (SQL wouldn't recognize it as a built-in function for some reason).  Anyway, for the record I ran the following query and got all of my suspect records:

```
SELECT *
FROM ACCT_LIST
where IsNumeric([ACCT_NUM_CHAR]) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `PATINDEX` function:

```
DECLARE @s VARCHAR(20) = '123123'
SELECT PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', @s)
```

If `@s` variable will have something different from range `0-9` this function will return the index of first occurence of non digit symbol. If all symbols are digits it will return `0`.